# Why can't my singleton class return a value that will stay in scope

Tags: objective-c

Stick with me. I'm visually impaired, have never used this site before, and will probably not post this in precisely the format that you are all used to. I apologize for any unintentional faux pas's herein.

Using Objective-C in an iOS project…

I have a singleton class, set up in what appears to be the usual way for Objective-C. It is, in the main, a series of methods which accept NSString values, interprets them, and return something else. In the code below, I'm simplifying things to the barest minimum, to emphasize the problem I am having.

From the singleton class:

```
- (NSUInteger) assignControlState:(NSString *)state {
    // excerpted for clarity...
    return UIControlStateNormal; // an example of what might be returned
}
```

Now, an instance of another class tries to use this method like so:

```
- (void) buttonSetup:(UIButton*)button {
    [button setTitle:@"something" forState:[[SingletonClass accessToInstance] assignControlState:@"normal"]];
}
```

This code actually works. HOwever, when the system goes to draw the UI which includes the button whose title was set in this way, an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occurs.

If the assignControlState method is moved into the same class as the buttonSetup method, no error is generated.

I'm guessing this is something about Apple's memory management that I'm not fully understanding, and how things go in and out of scope, but for the life of me, I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

HOpe someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell with those lines of code. Start with the debugger attached (not just debug mode), and you will get very useful information.

Comment: This has nothing to do with scope. This is simply incorrect memory management, which is normally unrelated to scope in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your accessToInstance method. I'll bet you are under-retaining. The implementation should be more like this:

```
static SingletonClass *sSingletonClass = nil;

@implementation

+ (id)accessToInstance {
  if (sSingletonClass == nil) {
    sSingletonClass = [[[self class] alloc] init];
  }
  return sSingletonClass;
}
@end
```

Now, if your program is following normal memory management rules, the singleton will stay around. You can check by writing:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [super dealloc];  // <-- set a breakpoint here.
}
```

If the debugger ever stops at this breakpoint, you know something in your program has over-released the singleton.

Comment: Thanks. HOwever, your implementation of the singleton is identical to mine in essentials, as far as I can see. I did, however, check if the dealloc was being called on the singleton. It isn't.

Comment: A weird thing: if I simply use NSLog() to output the value returned by the singleton's method, it will print it out, go about its business, and eventually lock up with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error again. COmmenting out NSLog() prevents the problem. It seems like using the singleton for absolutely anything causes a problem, even if nothing ever tries to reference the data it returned at all. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

You know that bit you excerpted for clarity?  I think you need to show us what it is because there's probably an over release in it somewhere.

Specifically, I think you release an autoreleased object.  If you do that and don't use the object again, everything will carry on normally until the autorelease pool gets drained.  The autorelease pool gets drained automatically at the end of the event at about the same time as the drawing normally occurs.

That would also explain the delayed crash following the NSLogs.